# Singular or plural verb after units of measure

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Should the verb in the following sentences be singular or plural?

> - Two cups of sugar [*was* or *were*] added to the recipe.
> - Fifty cubic yards of contaminated soil [*was* or *were*] excavated.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include links and quotes from relevant reference materials that you have consulted and tell why you need additional information that isn't there?

Comment: Singular or plural is not a matter of tense but rather of number.

Comment: Recast the sentences in the active voice and the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, with units of measure, one uses a singular verb.  For example, if you are most interested in a single quantity of sugar, that happens to be two cups, you would say two cups of sugar was added to the recipe.  In fact, it might have been half of a 1-quart measure, or it might have been four half-cup measures.

Almost certainly, you are uninterested in whether the fifty cubic yards of earth was added in fifty increments or otherwise.

See, for example https://www.aje.com/en/author-resources/articles/editing-tip-singular-and-plural-verbs-measured-quantities.

Consider also the following sentences:

> *Two cups are too much sugar for that recipe!
>
> Two cups is too much sugar for that recipe!
>
> *Fifty cubic yards were a lot more contaminated soil than we anticipated.
>
> Fifty cubic yards was a lot more contaminated soil than we anticipated.

As an aside, you can avoid this by using the active voice, which many style guides prefer when a choice is possible:

> The baker added two cups of sugar to the recipe.
>
> The contractor excavated 50 cubic yards of soil.

Comment: and even when the measured quantity is not a mass noun:  Two cups of eggs was added.

Comment: Do I still use a singular verb if cup is not used as the unit of capacity but literally as a cup? E.g. 5 cups of water was/were poured into the container?

Comment: @downvote-flagger if there were five cups full of water that were all poured into the container then yes, I would probably use the plural verb.

Answer (score -1):

Don't let the prepositional phrase (of sugar, of contaminated soil) fool you. The subject-verb agreement depends on the base noun. So you have:

> Two **cups** *were* added...
>
> Fifty cubic **yards** *were* excavated...

In each case, the base noun is plural. The adjectival prepositional phrases that complete the noun phrase are of no import.

For reference, see point 5 at [this OWL link](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/01/).

Comment: The most applicable example in your link seems to be *five dollars is a lot of money,* which contradicts your answer.

Comment: @phoog Check out the fifth block, starting with: "5. Do not be misled by a phrase that comes between the subject and the verb. The verb agrees with the subject, not with a noun or pronoun in the phrase."

Comment: But none of the examples demonstrates a unit of measure, which is an exception to that rule.  For example, *fifty gallons is a lot of water.*

Comment: @phoog Do you disagree with my answer that the plural forms are correct in this instance? Units of measure *can* constitute an exception, but those examples are structurally distinct.

Comment: I do disagree with your answer.  See mine for more detail.